# Why is Rails/RSpec not able to render & in test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer

I've got a mailer. And a view for that mailer. While in preview, everything
looks fine, and links render properly.

The problem is writing specs (RSpec). When I try to test the presence of some links the test fails because the '&' ampersand in the link is not displayed correctly in the test:

What I test for (and as it appears in mailer preview):

```
https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/set_identcodes.do?lang=de&idc=1234567890
```

What I see in the test output when the test fails:

```
https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/set_identcodes.do?lang=de&amp;idc=1234567890
```

So, how can I make sense of that? 
Why is the mail interpreted differently in the preview and in the test? 
And how am I supposed to test that?

Comment: `&amp;` is an url-escaped escaped `&`. When you say "this is how it appears in mailer preview", you mean "this is what I see", don't you? In which case, it is very likely that the ampersand is still escaped, but it is not obvious. Inspect the page source to find the truth.

Comment: I figured that one is escaped the other one not, but why does Rails/RSpec make it so difficult to know what to expect? If the mailer preview displays everything right, why is RSpec not using the same representation but forces the developer to think about character escaping?

Comment: I think they are both escaped. it's just that in preview the browser handles the escaping and shows you  the intended output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test output is escaped html. You may transform your expectation to escaped html as well:

```
expected_link = 'https://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/set_identcodes.do?lang=de&idc=1234567890'
expect(page).to have_content(ERB::Util.html_escape(expected_link))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question was also aiming at finding out why there is a difference in how preview and RSpec interprete one and the same view. It would be much easier and intuitive iof I could test for the link as I use it and as I want it to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

### Try using `CGI.escapeHTML()`.

I was running into the same issue with `&` being turned into `&amp;`.

You can try using `CGI.escapeHTML()` to try and escape the HTML and turn characters, like ampersands `&` into their HTML code `&amp;`.

```
it { is_expected.to include CGI.escapeHTML( expected_link ) }
```